# Google App Engine repackaged error

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to run Google App Engine Endpoints on my development environment, with the ff configuration:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter();
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.28'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.28'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.28'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.28'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.12'

    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    compile group: 'org.tuckey', name: 'urlrewritefilter', version: '4.0.4'

    compile group: 'com.google.appengine.tools', name: 'appengine-gcs-client', version: '0.6'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }

    jvmFlags = ["-Ddatastore.backing_store=\"/<some local path>/local_db.bin\""]
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>WARN</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mypackagename.MyEndpoint,
com.mypackagename.SecondEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I get the ff errors when running the dev server, and when invoking an endpoint, though the endpoint method can be executed in the server:

```
Jul 31, 2017 9:59:37 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams$LimitedInputStream. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(MethodVisitor.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:959)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:693)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.rewrite(Transformer.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:113)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:199)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent.writeTo(AbstractInputStreamContent.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.postRequest(CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.java:76)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.generateDiscoveryDoc(CloudDiscoveryDocGenerator.java:56)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.DiscoveryService.ensureDiscoveryDocsCached(DiscoveryService.java:109)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.DiscoveryService.handle(DiscoveryService.java:144)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.doSingleBackendCall(ApiServlet.java:309)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:512)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

(It's actually a series of Exceptions saying "com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
    SEVERE: Unable to instrument {classname}. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated")

It seems to me the com.google.appengine.repackaged library is causing the issue. (Is this correct?)

UPDATE:
The same type of exception  is (sometimes) raised when invoking an Objectify method inside the Endpoint, causing no update into the datastore.

```
Aug 01, 2017 9:56:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer transform
SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$Cursor. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(MethodVisitor.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:959)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:693)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.rewrite(Transformer.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:113)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:199)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryRunnerV3.runQuery(QueryRunnerV3.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.runQuery(PreparedQueryImpl.java:31)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.asQueryResultIterator(PreparedQueryImpl.java:60)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeysOnlyIterator.<init>(KeysOnlyIterator.java:24)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.StuffingIterator.<init>(StuffingIterator.java:16)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryEngine$3.iterator(QueryEngine.java:86)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.iterator(QueryImpl.java:358)
    at com.goldsoft.api.testguestbook.domain.AppUser.loadByUniqueUserId(AppUser.java:368)
    at com.goldsoft.api.testguestbook.domain.AppUser.validateUser(AppUser.java:410)
    at com.goldsoft.api.testguestbook.OrganizationEndpoint.insert(OrganizationEndpoint.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
```

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? Would really appreciate some input to help clarify this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloud Endpoints offers a [getting started](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) guide which you could try to follow and base your configuration upon. Have you tried that? Or is it not relevant to your use case?